# Google images search Xpath - extract part of Text()

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, web-crawler

I'm in a need of a lot of images. A good source for this is of course Google Image search.

I have been playing around with finding the best way to do this. Getting the smaller "thumbnail" images is possible but I would like to have the original sizes.

Using:

```
 //*[@id="rg_s"]/div/div/text()
```

I do find an URL to the original size. Ex:

```
{"cb":9,"cl":9,"cr":9,"ct":9,"id":"twpCKa-qACVbrM:","isu":"twitter.com",
"itg":false,"ity":"jpg","oh":512,"ou":
"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/698459967624474624/FsezpZpl.jpg",
"ow":512,"pt":"Manchester United (@ManUtd) | Twitter","rid":"5Q1F7uGUbUotPM",
"ru":"https://twitter.com/manutd","s":"","sc":1,"th":225,"tu":
"https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images? 
q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcRELkTX0VqGU4OHs9sgS93dedTCNsW0TvJT3S72YuOCCHfXxZSa","tw":225}
```

With:
**https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/698459967624474624/FsezpZpl.jpg**

Being the URL to the original size. I dont really know where this textblock actually can be found on the site. But what I'm wondering is if the URL it self can be isolated and extracted?

Comment: Not in XPath. You'd need to parse the inner JSON with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extract parts of a JSON-value with XPath, but you could use regex on the text-value you found with XPath. Ex:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Load XML ....
            //string s = xml.SelectSingleNode('//*[@id="rg_s"]/div/div/text()').Value
            string s = @"{""cb"":9,""cl"":9,""cr"":9,""ct"":9,""id"":""twpCKa-qACVbrM:"",""isu"":""twitter.com"",
""itg"":false,""ity"":""jpg"",""oh"":512,""ou"":
""https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/698459967624474624/FsezpZpl.jpg"",
""ow"":512,""pt"":""Manchester United (@ManUtd) | Twitter"",""rid"":""5Q1F7uGUbUotPM"",
""ru"":""https://twitter.com/manutd"",""s"":"""",""sc"":1,""th"":225,""tu"":
""https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images? 
q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcRELkTX0VqGU4OHs9sgS93dedTCNsW0TvJT3S72YuOCCHfXxZSa"",""tw"":225}";

            Console.WriteLine(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s, "\"ou\":\\s*?\"([^\"]+)\"").Groups[1].Value);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't responded sooner, thanks alot for the help. I haven't used a lot of regex before so if that can be explained a bit further it would help a lot. I guess "\"ou\":\\s*?\"([^\"]+)\"").Groups[1].Value means it finds "ou" and grabs the link some way.

Comment: When it finds `ou:"somevalue"`, it matches and stores `somevalue` in a capture group `( .. )`, then you access that group and get the value. See Regex101 for demo and explanation: https://regex101.com/r/cQ3uZ8/1